# How to make RecyclerView to width="wrap_content"

Tags: android, center, android-recyclerview

I want to make RecyclerView like this one:

[image]

But in my case, child view doesn't set as `width="wrap_content"`  or it RecyclerView doesn't set as `width="wrap_content"` and on `"center"`

[image]

Here is RecyclerView in activity_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is setting Adapter onCreate:

```
    public void initRecyclerView(List<Invitation> invitationList) {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), invitationList));
    }
```

here is my Adapter:

```
public class ItemGridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemGridAdapter.ViewHolderItem> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<Invitation> list;
    private final DrawableHelper drawableHelper;

    public ItemGridAdapter(Context context, List<Invitation> list) {
        this.context=context;
        this.list=list;
        this.drawableHelper = new DrawableHelper();
    }

    @Override
    public ItemGridAdapter.ViewHolderItem onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_grid, parent, false);
        return new ItemGridAdapter.ViewHolderItem(context,view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemGridAdapter.ViewHolderItem viewHolder, int position) {
        Invitation invitation = list.get(position);
        viewHolder.position=position;
        Picasso.with(context)
               .load(invitation.getCustomUser().getAvatar())
               .transform(new CircleTransformation())
               .placeholder(drawableHelper.getDrawableForName(invitation.getCustomUser().getFullName()))
               .into(viewHolder.userIcon);
        if (invitation.getYelpID()!=null&&invitation.getYelpID().length()>0){
            viewHolder.votedIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            viewHolder.votedIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolderItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView votedIcon;
        public ImageView userIcon;
        Context mContext;
        int position;
        public ViewHolderItem(Context mContext,View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.mContext = mContext;
            userIcon=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.userIcon); 
            votedIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.votedIcon);
        }
    }

}
```

here is layout of item R.layout.item_grid for adapter :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center">


        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/userIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/votedIcon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_voted"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you nesting **2** RelativeLayouts? **1** is more than enough.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein to add white_circle below User image

Comment: @FrankN.Stein why not?

Comment: Because nesting layouts is **bad for performances**. Just add another `ImageView` under the other one.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein ok, updated layout...but still RecyclerView is not in center with wrap_content

Comment: The solution here is to use a GridView **for every row**. In the first image, it's **2** GridViews. In the second image there's only one, so it's aligned... as a grid (every cell is aligned to the others). Different rows **in the same GridView** won't stretch. But different GridViews will behave independently.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein " it's 2 GridViews"?? NO it's not. if there will be 10 rows of items?  I need to add 10 GridViews?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein You are kidding me? It is more bad for performances then 2 RelativeLayouts))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96231/discussion-between-frank-n-stein-and-nick-unuchek).

Comment: Did you ever use a ListView with custom rows? Every GridView is a row.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Support Library as of 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com) supports this WRAP_CONTENT in RecyclerView by default.